# How to resolve a TypeError: string indices must be integers, with list comprehension over list of dicts?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

Can somebody please explain to me why this works:
(standalone)

```
numpy_data = np.array([[1, [{'id': 1495, 'name': 'fishing'}, {'id': 12392, 'name': 'best friend'}]], 
                   [3, [{‘id’: 818, ‘name’: ‘based on novel’}, {‘id’: 10131, ‘name’: ‘interracial relationship’}]]])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=numpy_data, index=[“row1”, “row2"], columns=[“id”, “keywords_text”])
    df[‘keywords_list’] = df[‘keywords_text’].apply(lambda column_value : ” “.join([sub[‘name’] for sub in column_value]))
    df.head(20)
```

Here is the output from the head command:

```
df is a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> datatype
       id   keywords_text                                       keywords_list
==== =====  =================================================== ========================
row1    1   [{'id': 1495, 'name': 'fishing'}, {'id': 12392...   fishing best friend
row2    3   [{'id': 818, 'name': 'based on novel'}, {'id':...   based on novel interracial relationship
```

And this does not:
(this is from the Kaggle Movies dataset, the keywords file)

```
df_movie_keywords[‘keywords_list’] = df_movie_keywords[‘keywords’].apply(lambda column_value : ” “.join([sub[‘name’] for sub in column_value]))
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1473-18a756783d63> in <module>
     15 
     16 # df_movie_keywords['keywords_list'] = df_movie_keywords.apply(lambda row: string_all_keywords(row), axis=1)
---> 17 df_movie_keywords['keywords_list'] = df_movie_keywords['keywords'].apply(lambda column_value : " ".join([sub['name'] for sub in column_value]))
     18 
     19 # df['keywords_list'] = df['keywords_text'].apply(lambda column_value : " ".join([sub['name'] for sub in column_value]))
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
<ipython-input-1473-18a756783d63> in <lambda>(column_value)
     15 
     16 # df_movie_keywords['keywords_list'] = df_movie_keywords.apply(lambda row: string_all_keywords(row), axis=1)
---> 17 df_movie_keywords['keywords_list'] = df_movie_keywords['keywords'].apply(lambda column_value : " ".join([sub['name'] for sub in column_value]))
     18 
     19 # df['keywords_list'] = df['keywords_text'].apply(lambda column_value : " ".join([sub['name'] for sub in column_value]))
<ipython-input-1473-18a756783d63> in <listcomp>(.0)
     15 
     16 # df_movie_keywords['keywords_list'] = df_movie_keywords.apply(lambda row: string_all_keywords(row), axis=1)
---> 17 df_movie_keywords['keywords_list'] = df_movie_keywords['keywords'].apply(lambda column_value : " ".join([sub['name'] for sub in column_value]))
     18 
     19 # df['keywords_list'] = df['keywords_text'].apply(lambda column_value : " ".join([sub['name'] for sub in column_value]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code as ASCII, not unicode. Smart quotes and the like make it difficult for people to run it easily (and therefore help get you an answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `keywords` column is a string not a list of dicts
- Fix it with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
- File from Kaggle: [The Movies Dataset - keywords.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset/download/zPeWVcFHd4FVILkEkFTP%2Fversions%2FUr5p8EUb593KaWc1xRXm%2Ffiles%2Fkeywords.csv?datasetVersionNumber=7)

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('keywords.csv')

print(type(df.keywords[0]))

>>> <class 'str'>

df.keywords = df.keywords.apply(literal_eval)

print(type(df.keywords[0]))

>>> <class 'list'>

df['keywords_list'] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda column_value : " ".join([sub['name'] for sub in column_value]))

print(df.head)

0    jealousy toy boy friendship friends rivalry bo...
1    board game disappearance based on children's b...
2     fishing best friend duringcreditsstinger old men
3    based on novel interracial relationship single...
4    baby midlife crisis confidence aging daughter ...
Name: keywords_list, dtype: object
```

Comment: Trenton - it works with your solution.  Thank you for the expeditious, and excellent answer!

I hope that others can get value from this too.